# Transforming columns in xdf files

Tags: r, transform, factors, revoscaler

Kindly advise on this code to transform a column, "Rate" into a factor named "Home_new"

```
rxDataStep(RED_xdf, RED_xdf, transforms = list(Home_new = factor(Rate))
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: SO rules: You need to post a complete example. Need data and any necessary `library` calls, and explain what efforts you have made to search for an answer on your own. . R rules: Generally one needs to make an assignment of the value of a function call, rather than just executing a function.